# Random get variabel showing up in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get, dns

I have a domain, let's call it example.com.

Whenever I go to http://example.com/ I'm redirected to http://example.com/?v=[insert random 12-digit alphanumeric string here]

This causes a great deal of trouble as the rewrite of the url periodically gets me thrown out of WordPress Admin (the variable was there before WordPress was installed though, so I assume its not causing the issue).

I have checked through .htaccess and DNS files for the domain, but I cant for the life of me figure out where its coming form.

By this point anything that can even point me in remotely the right direction is greatly appreciated, like its purpose or if anyone has ever seen it before.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details about this. Something is definitely doing that redirect. Either it's in .htaccess, a plugin is doing it or something completely different.

Comment: I've checked .htaccess, and thats not doing anything. And it cant be wp or a wp plugin, because it was there before i installed wordpress altogether.

Comment: What details would you need?